# Execution time of a spring boot job

Tags: performance, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to calculate the total time taken by a spring batch job. I have used spring boot to trigger the job. Before spring boot triggers the spring batch job, datasource and other beans required by job are configured by spring boot which consumes some time. Should i consider this time also to calculate total amount of time taken by spring boot job for execution as it uses the datasources and beans configured by spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

> Should i consider this time also to calculate total amount of time
>   taken by spring boot job

Simple answer is NO. Unless you reconnect the datasource and refresh the configuration on each execution of the Job.

When you say, your application (boot or batch) is up and ready for execution, it mean all the components are initialised, dependencies are resolved, connections are made and it is just waiting for a task/trigger to start execution.

This mean, the time taken by the datasource config or context setting is not part of your job execution time.

Comment: Got your point. But, the reason i thought i should include datasource and bean initialization time is because - my job is triggered by spring boot application which is inturn triggered by a scheduler tool.               So, the scenario is like every time job is triggered, its using a new datasource connections and spring context made due to the spring boot application trigger by job scheduler. So, do u think i need to include that time as well now because its like i use new DB connections n bean initialisation everytime i want to trigger the job?

Answer (score 0):

> Should i consider this time also to calculate total amount of time taken by spring boot job for execution

It depends on what you want to measure. If you want to measure the execution time of the whole spring boot app (from the OS point of view, the total time of running your JVM process), then yes you need to include everything.

If you want to measure the execution time of your Spring Batch job and only that, you can use a `JobExecutionListener`, like for example:

```
class ExecutionTimeJobListener implements JobExecutionListener {

   private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExecutionTimeJobListener.class);
   private StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();

   @Override
   public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
      stopWatch.start();
   }

   @Override
   public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
      stopWatch.stop();
      logger.info("Job took " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeSeconds() + "s");
   }
}
```